# Is the Question/Answer database open?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump

I'd love to build an IRC bot that integrated with QA database of stackoverflow. Is the database open so I can reuse the answers? Can we get a dump of it anywhere (like Wikipedia offers)?

Comment: Great idea. The open source Supybot (supybot.sf.net) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to "reuse the answers":

- The [Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump) - The database of past question, answers, comments, badges, etc. (updated monthly)
- The upcoming [Stack Overflow API](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/what-would-a-stack-overflow-api-look-like/) - A preliminary exploration of providing a programming interface to Stack Overflow (currently read-only)

Answer (score 2):

It sure is: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Answer (score 0):

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dump for many interesting applications and analyses of the data. Please consider announcing your project here when you have something we can play with!